# Unable to extract IP camera firmware

Tags: linux, firmware, ip-camera

I am trying to extract the [firmware](https://bizpartner.panasonic.net/public/file/wv-s2511ln-etc-firmware?category=2025) for a Panasonic WV-S2131L. It comes as a .zip file that contains a .img file. I have tried many methods to try to analyze this file and I have found nothing of value.

Binwalk returned absolutely nothing

xxd at least gave me back the firmware version

> `xxd -a s1131_402ES.img | head
>   00000000: 342e 3032 4530 0000 302e 3030 0000 0000  4.02E0..0.00....
>   00000010: 1314 0000 1314 0000 0004 0000 8000 b003  ................
>   00000020: 1f06 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
>   00000030: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 8000  ................
>   00000040: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 8000 0000 2003  .............. .
>   00000050: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 a003 9601 0000  ................
>   00000060: 0100 0000 0000 0000 0100 0000 0000 0000  ................
>   00000070: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 797d  ..............y}
>   00000080: 5e12 3e81 1370 6400 a6fa c4e5 058b 3136  ^.>..pd.......16
>   00000090: 5630 f8f0 2878 5f56 7788 279b a597 114c  V0..(x_Vw.'....L`

A complete hex dump revealed no recognizable string

FDisk said there was no recognizable file system

7zip thinks it's corrupt

I am completely stumped. I just want to view the filesystem, how can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

This firmware appears to be encrypted and so you will not be able to simply extract a filesystem.

If you run `binwalk -E some_image.img` against the firmware you will see what I mean.

Check the below link for a propper example of how to verify if a file is encrypted or not based on its entropy.

http://www.devttys0.com/2013/06/differentiate-encryption-from-compression-using-math/